# How do I fix error code CS1705? (Assembly X uses Y which has a higher version than referenced assembly Y)

Tags: c#, build, compiler-errors, project, .net-assembly

I'm facing an issue when trying to build a csproj, after trying to build I get this single error:

"`Error CS1705  Assembly 'System.DirectoryServices' with identity 'System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' uses 'System.ComponentModel.Primitives, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Primitives' with identity 'System.ComponentModel.Primitives, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'`

And here's the csproj code with the dll refrences:  [ProjectCSPROJ](https://pastebin.com/raw/zhdE9K5e)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Remove the reference and make sure that the .csproj file is clean. And add reference again.